# Combine multiple videos with specific duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I am going to concat multiple videos so I can get one video file with FFmpeg.

I've found several ways to implement this but all ways I found can't concat with specific duration of each video.

It means they only concat whole videos.

Exactly, what I wanted is to insert video1 into video2 with specific time. While searching several articles related with this, I checked many articles say "It is impossible with ffmpeg".

So I am trying to split video2 into two videos( like video2-1,video2-2) and concat video1, video2-1, video2-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can do is using trim and atrim in filter complex.

example

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[1:v]trim=3:6,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:a]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[1:a]atrim=3:6,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];[v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" out.mp4
```

this will cut vid1 from 0 to 2 and vid2 from 3 tot 6 and combine those together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I run this command but I get this error.                                         
"Invalid file index 0 in filtergraph description [0:v]trim=0:2[v1];[1:v]trim=3:6[v2];[0:a]atrim=0:2[a1];[1:a]atrim=3:6[a2];[v1][a2][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1."

Comment: I just modified it. small typo at concat. Should be [v1][a1][v2][a2] instead of [v1][a2][v2][a2]

Comment: I wrote "- i" instead of "-i". remove the space between the "-" and "i"

Comment: Also good te reset time. So full command:  `ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[1:v]trim=3:6,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:a]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[1:a]atrim=3:6,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];[v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" out.mp4`

Comment: Nice. It works very well. Big thanks to Dirk V!  Can you please help me once again ? I want to concat three videos with such way. How can I set filter parameters ?

Comment: basically the same thing, just concat with n=3, `ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]trim=3:6,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[2:v]trim=3:6,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[0:a]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[1:a]atrim=3:6,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[2:a]atrim=0:2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];[v0][a0][v1][a1][v2][a2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1" out.mp4`